# How to choose texture layer from texture array for rendering in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm loading 3 textures into array

```
int width = 1024;
int height = 1024;
GLuint ID;
glGenTextures(1, &ID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 3)
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[0]);
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 1, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[1]);
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 2, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[2]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
```

If I use immediate mode how can I tell which layer I want to use to draw from texture by glTexCoord2f(...) after glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ID)? Do I must use some specific methods?

Answer (score 2):

Immediate mode is not the issue, the fixed function pipeline is - texture arrays can only be sampled using shaders. If you use shaders, you can use some way to pass the required layer index to the shader (as attribute - generic or builtin, as uniform, using some other buffer objects, caluclate it from something else, whatever...).

If you use the fixed function pipeline, there is simply no way. You could only switch to 3D textures to emulate the array textures, but will hit much stricter size limits, and much more overhead when sampling with filters.

However, there are really no good reasons to use  immediate mode and/or fixed function pipeline at all in 2017. These stuff has been deprecated a decade ago.

Comment: I will change it to VBO later, is it possible to make it without shaders? I never used them.

Comment: @ground0: What part of "texture arrays can only be sampled using shaders" left you room to think that you could avoid using shaders?